# Convert CIImage to Data without loading image into memory Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to convert a `CIImage` to a `Data` object like so:

```
let context = CIContext(options: [.useSoftwareRenderer: false])

if let colorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB) {
    let croppedImageData = context.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: colorSpace)
}
```

This works and the result is fine however when looking at the allocations in instruments every time I run this piece of code the memory allocated is upwards of 240 MB which is obviously way to much.

I would like to simply convert the CIImage to Data (for storing reasons) without it taking up so much memory even if it's just a split second.

I've tried to use `autoreleasepool` and tried it on another thread but the jumps in allocations remains the same.

[image: Image allocation]

Thankfully it doesn't stay in memory and is released but the fact that it spikes is troublesome. The CIImage extent is `(0.0, 0.0, 2250.0, 3000.0)` which probably why it's taking so much memory to convert.

Suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Turns out that because I applied a CIFilter (https://cifilter.io/CIPerspectiveCorrection/) the spike in memory was way larger, when using a unfiltered ciimage it goes up to about 60MB instead of the filtered version which jumps to about 260MB. Unfortunately I don't think this can be fixed unless we remove the CIFilter.